# Can we call User control code behind method using Jquery ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do something, Can we call User control code behind method using Jquery ajax ?
likes:

ASCX CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Uploads.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
```

ASCX.CS

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

But its will create an error please can any one what do i am wrong.

Comment: Why even go down that road? You should create a web API.

Comment: Thats my requirement i can't used web services / webapi like that.

Comment: What's the error? Can you edit the question and put it in?

Comment: "Unknown web method GetCurrentTime." this error show

Comment: but I write GetCurrentTime function in ASPX page then it will working fine, but these code write in a ascx.cs page then it will error accured "UnKnown web method GetCurrentTime" 
I think can't call usercontrol method with jquery ajax

Comment: Based on my eariler research, I came to know that codebehind method in ascx control can not be directly exposed as AJAX webservice methods(called via Page methods collection). We have to modify the page's codebehind so as to support some certain ajax function calls. I would suggest call it from your .aspx page and it will work like charm..

Comment: I know very well what you are saying but its my problem and i think every problem have a solution.

I see that how can gone to the this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user control doesn't have all the functionality of a page and can't be called directly.Check out the following link for complete solution
[Creating a Page method (ScriptMethod) within an ASCX user control using AJAX, JSON, base classes and reflection](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aMkyMaQCS3mIJ%3awww.chadscharf.com/index.php/2009/11/creating-a-page-method-scriptmethod-within-an-ascx-user-control-using-ajax-json-base-classes-and-reflection/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk)